# Stored procedure returns wrong value in asp.net web api

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures

I wrote some procedure code which is return value `1` when it runs successfully.

But it always returns `-1`(Failed value) when it goes well in `ASP.NET Web API`.

I tested in `SSMS` with this case.

```
USE [MY_DATABASE]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[API_TO_WEB_CREATE_RESOURCE]
        @RES_Size = 3019,
        @RES_ContentType = N'image/jpeg',
        @RES_OriginalName = N'evolving_google_identity_share.jpg',
        @RES_GUID = N'b98bd7ee-cb19-49c8-a8dc-3b92b3210b91',
        @RES_Path = N'~/Content/resources\\b98bd7ee-cb19-49c8-a8dc-3b92b3210b91',
        @RES_Upload_USR_Index = NULL

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

This returns `1`

---

Same code in `ASP.NET Web API`.

```
int result = context.API_TO_WEB_CREATE_RESOURCE(
                            3019,
                            "image/jpeg",
                            "evolving_google_identity_share.jpg",
                            "b98bd7ee-cb19-49c8-a8dc-3b92b3210b91",
                            "~/Content/resources\\b98bd7ee-cb19-49c8-a8dc-3b92b3210b91",
                            null
                            );
```

This returns `-1`

And this is my procedure.

```sql
USE [MY_DATABASE]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:  
-- Create date: 
-- Description: 
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[API_TO_WEB_CREATE_RESOURCE]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @RES_Size int = 0,
    @RES_ContentType nvarchar(100) = NULL,
    @RES_OriginalName nvarchar(300),
    @RES_GUID nvarchar(50),
    @RES_Path nvarchar(500),
    @RES_Upload_USR_Index int = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RES_RegisteredDatetime datetime = GETDATE()
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN

            INSERT INTO 
                dbo.NS_Resource (RES_Size, RES_ContentType, RES_OriginalName, RES_GUID, RES_Path, RES_Upload_USR_Index) 
            VALUES (@RES_Size, @RES_ContentType, @RES_OriginalName, @RES_GUID, @RES_Path, @RES_Upload_USR_Index);

            PRINT '리소스 추가됨'
        COMMIT TRAN

        RETURN(1); 
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        DECLARE @ERROR_Msg nvarchar = error_message()
        RAISERROR('리소스 추가 중 문제 발생됨 %s', 16, 1, @ERROR_Msg)
        RETURN (-1)
    END CATCH
END
```

### Summary

#### Expected

Return value `1` and insert new value successfully.

#### Actual

- In SSMS

Return Value `1` and insert new value successfully.

- In ASP.NET Web API (This is the problem)

Return Value `-1` and insert new value successfully.

Comment: can you enable the profiler and check what input values are getting passed?

Comment: @PSK profiler? can u explain more? cause i'm noob

Comment: SQL Server have a profiling tool which logs all the queries being executed, you can enable it from your SSMS.

Comment: @PSK ok i tracked my sql query. It says `exec [dbo].[API_TO_WEB_CREATE_RESOURCE] @RES_Size=3019,@RES_ContentType=N'image/jpeg',@RES_OriginalName=N'evolving_google_identity_share.jpg',@RES_GUID=N'49af2e21-8683-4972-b888-3e6c588702fa',@RES_Path=N'~/Content/resources\49af2e21-8683-4972-b888-3e6c588702fa',@RES_Upload_USR_Index=NULL` from asp.net entity framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's never a good idea to have multiple `return` statements in a code module, and SQL is not an exception. Try to rewrite your procedure as follows and see if it will help:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[API_TO_WEB_CREATE_RESOURCE]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @RES_Size int = 0,
    @RES_ContentType nvarchar(100) = NULL,
    @RES_OriginalName nvarchar(300),
    @RES_GUID nvarchar(50),
    @RES_Path nvarchar(500),
    @RES_Upload_USR_Index int = NULL
AS

DECLARE @RES_RegisteredDatetime datetime = GETDATE();
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @Ret int = -1; -- Failure by default

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN

        INSERT INTO 
            dbo.NS_Resource (RES_Size, RES_ContentType, RES_OriginalName, RES_GUID, RES_Path, RES_Upload_USR_Index) 
        VALUES (@RES_Size, @RES_ContentType, @RES_OriginalName, @RES_GUID, @RES_Path, @RES_Upload_USR_Index);

        PRINT '리소스 추가됨';
    COMMIT TRAN

    set @Ret = 1; -- Success
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    if @@trancount > 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN;

    DECLARE @ERROR_Msg nvarchar(2048) = error_message();
    RAISERROR('리소스 추가 중 문제 발생됨 %s', 16, 1, @ERROR_Msg);
END CATCH;

return @Ret;
go
```

However, the whole thing looks a bit cumbersome to me. If you are throwing the error to the client from inside the `catch` block, this should be enough. It will translate into an SQLException in C#, so return value becomes rather irrelevant.

Personally, I don't use the return value; instead, I usually create 2 output parameters, `int` for the number and `nvarchar(2048)` for the error message, and assign their values in the `catch` block without re-throwing. When execution is completed I simply check the value of the `@ErrorNumber` output parameter, and if it's neither zero nor NULL, I process the error on the client side.

Comment: Awesome advise and it works using output value instead of return value. Ty.